# Magento 2.3 - Paypal Credit Wont Go away from MiniCart

Tags: magento2.3

I 100% have Paypal Credit disabled in all sections of Configuration -> Payment methods.

The only section enabled is Paypal Express Checkout, and "advertise PayPal Credit" is definteluy not filled in. All the other Paypal sections that are not enabled also have "Enable Paypal Credit" set to "No"

Yet, I am still getting the checkout with PayPal credit on my minicart.

Only in Magento Version 2.3. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked in website and store views too?

Comment: yes i checked. I am only using Paypal Express checkout....there is no option to not enable credit. Only under Paypal standard, and that option is not enabled.

Answer (score 6):

There is an option hidden away under many levels of the PayPal config! All funding options are enabled by default so you have to disable them even if the actual methods are disabled.

Stores > Config > Payment Methods > PayPal Configure > Basic Settings - PayPal Express Checkout > Advanced Settings > Frontend Experience Settings > Disable Funding Options

I am using 2.3.1 Commerce.

Answer (score 0):

```
bin/magento config:set paypal/style/disable_funding_options CREDIT,CARD,ELV
bin/magento cache:clean
```